# Could anyone prove this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does anybody knows how to prove that 
$$a+b+c =  \frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c$$ if  $$\frac {a^2−bc}{a(1−bc)}=\frac {b^2−ac}{b(1−ac)}$$ and 
$a\neq b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that, assuming $a,b\ne 0$, $bc\neq 1$ and $ac \neq 1$

$$\frac {a^2−bc}{a(1−bc)}=\frac {b^2−ac}{b(1−ac)}\iff (a^2−bc)b(1−ac)=(b^2−ac)a(1−bc)$$

$$a^2b-a^3bc-b^2c+ab^2c^2=ab^2-ab^3c-a^2c+a^2bc^2$$

$$a^2b-ab^2+a^2c-b^2c=-ab^3c+a^2bc^2+a^3bc-ab^2c^2$$

$$ab(a-b)+c(a-b)(a+b)=abc(a-b)(a+b)+abc^2(a-b)$$

$$ab+c(a+b)=abc(a+b)+abc^2$$

then divide by $abc$ which requires also $c\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for such deep explanation.

Comment: @ИммануилКант You are welcome! Bye